# Custom form with two file uploads to Google Drive only works half the time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a custom web form where people can upload their resume and license to my Google Drive. I found some code online, which I've modified a little, and it sort of works.

**code.gs**

```
var emailTo= "test@test.com"

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    var data = e.parameter.fileContent; // First attachment
    var filename = e.parameter.filename; // First attachment filename

    var data2 = e.parameter.fileContent2; // Second attachment
    var filename2 = e.parameter.filename2; // Second attachment filename

    var email = e.parameter.Email;
    var name = e.parameter.Name;
    var result=uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data,filename,data2,filename2,name,email,e);
    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(result) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form').setSandboxMode(
            HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

// new property service GLOBAL
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
// see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/

/**
 * select the sheet
 */
function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}

/**
 * record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
 * e is the data received from the POST
 */

function record_data(e,fileUrl,fileUrl2) {
  try {
    var doc     = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet ID");
    var sheet   = doc.getSheetByName('Responses'); // select the responses sheet

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row     = [ new Date() ]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp
    // loop through the header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column

      if(headers[i].length > 0 && headers[i] == "Resume") {
        row.push(fileUrl); // add data to row
      }

      else if(headers[i].length > 0 && headers[i] == "License") {
        row.push(fileUrl2); // add data to row
      }

      else if(headers[i].length > 0) {
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]); // add data to row
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
  finally {
    return;
  }

}

function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, data2, file2, name, email,e) {
  try {
    var dropbox = "Application Test";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
        bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file);
        var subfolder = folder.createFolder([name, email].join("-"));
        var file = subfolder.createFile(blob);
        var fileUrl=file.getUrl();

    var contentType2 = data2.substring(5,data2.indexOf(';')),
        bytes2 = Utilities.base64Decode(data2.substr(data2.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob2 = Utilities.newBlob(bytes2, contentType2, file2);
        var file2 = subfolder.createFile(blob2);
        var fileUrl2=file2.getUrl();       

        //Generating Email Body
        var html =  
    '<body>' + 
      '<h2> New Application </h2>' +
        '<p>Name : '+e.parameters.Name+'</p>' +
        '<p>Email : '+e.parameters.Email+'</p>' +
        '<p>Phone Number : '+e.parameters.Phone+'</p>' +
        '<p>Address : '+e.parameters.Address+'</p>' +
        '<p>Postal Code : '+e.parameters.Postal+'</p>' +
        '<p>File Name  : '+e.parameters.filename+'</p>' +
        '<p><a href='+file.getUrl()+'>Resume Link</a></p><br />' +
        '<p>File Name  : '+e.parameters.filename2+'</p>' +
        '<p><a href='+file2.getUrl()+'>License</a></p><br />' +
    '</body>';

    record_data(e,fileUrl,fileUrl2);

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, "New Application Recieved","New Application Request Recieved",{htmlBody:html});
        return file.getUrl() + file2.getUrl();
  } catch (f) {
    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"file upload failed",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(f) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

**Form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

  <form id="uploadForm" action="Insert Web App URL" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="fileContent" id="fileContent">
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="filename" id="filename">
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="fileContent2" id="fileContent2">
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="filename2" id="filename2">

  <label> Name : </label><input required type="text" value="" name="Name" id="Name"><br><br>
  <label> Email : </label> <input required type="text" value="" name="Email" id="Email"><br><br>
  <label> Phone Number : </label><input required type="text" value="" name="Phone" id="Phone"><br><br>
  <label> Address : </label> <input required type="text" value="" name="Address" id="Address"><br><br>
  <label> Postal Code : </label><input type="text" value="" name="Postal" id="Postal"><br><br>

</form>
<label> Resume: <input id="Resume" name="Resume" type="file"/>
<label> License: <input id="License" name="License" type="file"/><br><br>
<input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="UploadFile();" />

<script>

function UploadFile() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var file = document.getElementById('Resume').files[0];
  var reader2 = new FileReader();
  var file2 = document.getElementById('License').files[0];  


  reader.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('fileContent').value=reader.result;
    document.getElementById('filename').value=file.name;
    //document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit();
  }

  reader2.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('fileContent2').value=reader2.result;
    document.getElementById('filename2').value=file2.name;
    document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit();
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader2.readAsDataURL(file2);
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Usually it'll only upload one of the files (the license), and show a blank untitled file for the other, although it does upload both files correctly every few attempts.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, try this: Press Control+Shift+i, go to Console, and upload the files with the console open. See if there is any error and add it to your post.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but didn't receive any errors.

Comment: What's the file format of the license? If it's a pdf, try defining the [upload type](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#upload_types) = media for the request.